# If coefficients insignificant, direction of relationship between variables also insignificant?

Tags: multiple-regression, p-value

If my p-values for all variables are not significant, does looking at/discussing the direction of variables even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking no. As if you reject the fail to reject the Null-Hypothesis  (p>0.05) you are not sure that the effect and hence its direction is not just noise or randomness in your sample. However, in some settings (like small sample size domains) people argue that the p-value is not as relevant as long as the effect size is large enough. But this is only the case in very specific  scenarios and careful consideration.